# Handling 64 bit integers on a 32 bit iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, arm, nsuinteger

I would like to handle **64 bit unsigned integers** on a iPhone 4s (which of course has a 32 bit ARM 6 processor).

When trying to work with 64 bit unsigned integers, e.g. Twitter IDs, I have the following problem:

```
// Array holding the 64 bit integer IDs of the Tweets in a timeline:
NSArray *Ids =[timelineData valueForKeyPath:@"id"];

// I would like to get the minimum of these IDs:
NSUInteger minId = (NSUInteger) Ids.lastObject;
```

The array `Ids` contains the following numbers (= Tweet Ids):

```
491621469123018752,
491621468917477377,
491621465544851456,
491621445655867393
```

However, `minId` returns the incorrect value of `399999248` (instead of `491621445655867393`)

How can I find the minimum or the last object in an Array of 64 bit integers on an iPhone 4s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a type that is always 64 bit instead of `NSUInteger`. You can use `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long`. You also need to get the integer value out of the NSNumber (arrays can't store C types). to do this you need to call

```
uint64_t minID = [Ids.lastObject longLongValue];
```

#### Edit

Changed to use uint64_t in example code as it has been correctly pointed out this shows your intent better.

Comment: I would use `uint64_t` to indicate you specifically want a 64 bit data type.